# Can I escape braces in a java MessageFormat?

Tags: java, escaping, messageformat

I want to output some braces in a java MessageFormat. For example I know the following does not work:

```
MessageFormat.format("  public {0} get{1}() {return {2};}\n\n", type, upperCamel, lowerCamel);
```

Is there a way of escaping the braces surrounding "return {2}"?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You can put them inside single quotes e.g.

```
'{'return {2};'}'
```

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) for more details.

Answer (score 18):

The documentation for [MessageFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) knows the answer:

> Within a *String*, `"''"` represents a
> single quote. A *QuotedString* can
> contain arbitrary characters except
> single quotes; the surrounding single
> quotes are removed. An *UnquotedString*
> can contain arbitrary characters
> except single quotes and left curly
> brackets. Thus, a string that should
> result in the formatted message
> `"'{0}'"` can be written as `"'''{'0}''"`
> or `"'''{0}'''"`.

Comment: Looking for "escap" in this documentation link you posted yields zero results, so the documentation should be updated to include that obvious term, so I don't quite get that "Wow. Surprise!" sarcastic phrase. People read documentations differently, some use Ctrl + F, others not, you have to accept that.

Answer (score 14):

Use single quotes:

```
MessageFormat.format("  public {0} get{1}() '{'return {2};'}'\n\n",
                     type, upperCamel, lowerCamel);
```

If you want to actually *use* a single quote, just double it. The [JavaDoc for `MessageFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) gives this somewhat complicated example:

> Thus, a string that should result in
>   the formatted message `"'{0}'"` can be
>   written as `"'''{'0}''" or "'''{0}'''"`.

This is `''` for a single quote, then `'{'` for an escaped brace, then `0`, `'}'` for the closing brace and `''` for the closing quote.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("I want to see ticks and curly braces around '''{'{0}'}'''", "this"));
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see what exactly the result of this would be.

Answer (score -3):

you can use this regex with perl or any other language to escape curly brackets and single quotes (x27). It does not touch any placeholder e.g. `{0}`:

```sh
echo "#  'single' quote test \n\n public {0} get{1}() {return {2};}\n\n" | perl -pe 's/\x27/\x27\x27/g; s/\{([^0-9])/\x27\{\x27$1/g; s/([^0-9])\}/$1\x27\}\x27/g'
```

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant to a Java question