# How to escape a { character in a MessageFormat pattern string?

Tags: java, replace, placeholder, illegalargumentexception, messageformat

I have a string like the following.

**ABC {A WELL-KNOWN MAGICIAN} WILL PERFORM AT {0} FOR {1} HOURS.**

There is no placeholder for the first pair of curly braces. When I pass this string to MessageFormat.format(String, Object[]) method with an object array containing two strings to replace the placeholders {0} and {1}, I get the following error.

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: All argument identifiers have to be either non-negative numbers or strings following the pattern ([:ID_Start:] [:ID_Continue:]*).**

It appears that the first pair of brace is being parsed for the first placeholder and since it is not a valid placeholder, the error occurs.

How can I tell MessageFormat.format to ignore the first pair of curly braces and work with the other two?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187093/can-i-escape-braces-in-a-java-messageformat

Comment: I agree, my question is a duplicate of the one listed above.

Comment: I also believe the official documentation for this class is poorly illustrated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put a pair of single quotes around the part you don't want to be treated as parameter placeholders. i.e.

```
ABC '{A WELL-KNOWN MAGICIAN}' WILL PERFORM AT {0} FOR {1} HOURS.
```

Comment: Just like `SimpleDateFormat` uses apostrophes to escape non-placeholder text: `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm"`(T).

Comment: Thanks been stuck on that for a while!